# Writing random numbers to a text file, C Sharp?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write random numbers 1 through 10 to a text file, but im not really understanding how. What do these error codes mean?

This is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Random_Number_File_Writer
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int randomNumber = 0;


        StreamWriter outputFile;


        int number = int.Parse(Form1.Text);

        if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            outputFile = File.CreateText(saveFile.FileName);


            Random Rand = new Random();

            for (int count = 0; count < number; count++)
            {

                randomNumber = Rand.Next(1, 11);


                outputFile.WriteLine(randomNumber);


                MessageBox.Show("File saved in path:" + saveFile.FileName);
            }
               outputFile.Close();
        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");
        }
    }

    private void btn_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the TextBox.
        Form1.Text = "";
    }

    private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

These are the errors im getting:

Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form.Text'

Error   CS0103  The name 'saveFile' does not exist in the current context

Error   CS0103  The name 'saveFile' does not exist in the current context

Error   CS0103  The name 'saveFile' does not exist in the current context

Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form.Text'

Comment: You don't have a saveFile component. and instead of `Form1.Text` use `this.Text` or what ever your form is called.

Comment: Except `this.Text` is the title of the form and your comment refers to a text box. You need to use the name of the text box control instead of `Form1`.

Comment: Now im getting this error:'object' does not contain a definition for 'ShowDialog' and no accessible extension method 'ShowDialog' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.

Answer (score 0):

`Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form.Text'`

You're calling the class staticlly and accessing a non-static variable. Change this to `this.Text`. this gets the current object of a class, in your case Form1.

`Error CS0103 The name 'saveFile' does not exist in the current context`

you're referencing a variable called `saveFile` however, you have not declared it before you're using it.

e.g.

`object saveFile = new object()` where `object` is the right type.

in your case i think you need saveFile to be of the type fileDialog, see the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: when i do the object saveFile = new object(); i get this error: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ShowDialog' and no accessible extension method 'ShowDialog' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.

Comment: @j_chicago Okay put at this point you're just copy and pasting your exceptions to a forum on the internet. Have you googled? what have you tried to resolve this issue? what do you think is happening and should happen?